# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in javascript function:

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Got an error like "validation.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" for dropdown list while calling a javascript function from .aspx file.

**BlueINK.aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="diGuj" onchange="javascript:optionChange(this);" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem style="display:none">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="1">yes</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<td align="right" style="width: 172px">
       <strong id="durationHome" style="display:none"><span class="redtext">* </span> Duration :</strong>
</td>
<td class="auto-style1" align="left">
       <asp:DropDownList ID="joinMo1" runat="server" style="display:none">
             <asp:ListItem Selected Value="january">Jan</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Feb</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Mar</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Apr</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>May</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Jun</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Jul</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Aug</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Sep</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Oct</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Nov</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Dec</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

**Validation.js**

```
function optionChange(textObj) {
    a = textObj.value;
    if (a == 1) {
        document.getElementById("durationHome").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("joinMo1").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("durationHome").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("joinMo1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: check if this ` a = textObj.value;` have value first using Console.log(textObj.value;)

Comment: use `<asp:DropDownList ID="joinMo1" runat="server" style="display:none" clientidmode="static">`

Comment: add this after your function declaration and find out where program is not executing properly , console.log(textObj.value); console.log(typeof textObj.value); if the second console is number it should work fine , if 'a' value is string compare your a like if(a=="1") , then proceed to see if getElementById is working fine or not

Comment: Hi Krupa, did any of the solution work for u ?

Comment: @Clint No, any of these didn't work for me

Comment: @KrupaPatel, what line throws the error

Comment: @Clint  **document.getElementById("joinMo1").style.display = "block";**

Comment: just curious, were you able to get to a solution, I did some research and I don't see anything wrong with the below solutions pertaining to the question you posted. Is there any information missing, happy to help

Comment: @Clint Thank you so much for your constant support. Now we don't use it in our project.

Comment: @Clint Thank you so much for your constant support. Now we don't use it in our project.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
document.getElementById("<%= joinMo1.ClientID %>").style.display = "none/block";
```

In place of,

```
document.getElementById("joinMo1").style.display="none/block"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` in your asp control

**Example:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="joinMo1" runat="server" style="display:none" clientidmode="static">
```

**Reason:**

It is because JS is unable to read your asp control as a result it as null.